# R timeDate drops time in coersion

Tags: r, datetime

I have dates of the format: "2/9/2016 21:16"

When I attempt to coerce them to a timeDate, I receive the result: [1] [2016-02-03]

I would prefer to not have to write my own string manipulation, but I can and already have, but there has to be a better way.  I have a dataframe and I am attempting to do the following:

```
restData2 <- restData %>% 
  mutate(year = year(as.timeDate(Date)),
     month = month(as.timeDate(Date)),
     day = day(as.timeDate(Date)),
     timeCategory = converToTimeCategory(Date)
  )
```

Note, that day is not a function in timeDate either.  Day of Week and Day of year exist, I need Day of Month.

The data exists in a data frame.  The data is basic transaction data.

Comment: What package is `as.timeDate` from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David, you are confused.  R differentiates between *internal representation* and actual *formated display*. For all types.

And there is (once again) no need for timeDate, lubridate, or any other wrapper:

```
R> intxt <- c("2/9/2016 21:16", "2/11/2016 22:23")
R> parsed <- as.POSIXct(intxt, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
R> parsed
[1] "2016-09-02 21:16:00 CDT" "2016-11-02 22:23:00 CDT"
R> format(parsed, "%d %b %Y at %H:%M")
[1] "02 Sep 2016 at 21:16" "02 Nov 2016 at 22:23"
R>
```

Here we parse a datetime object into the standard `POSIXct`, specifying a format.  Which can be day-month or month-day; here I picked the former.

Given the `parsed` object, I first show the default display, and then a custom format string.

Lastly, if you must, you can also convert to `timeDate`:

```
R> library(timeDate)
R> as.timeDate(parsed)
GMT
[1] [2016-09-03 02:16:00] [2016-11-03 03:23:00]
R>
```

Not the timezone adjustment from my local (Central) time.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Here is the correct result using that formatting: restData$Date <- as.POSIXct(restData$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
restData2 <- restData %>% 
  mutate(year = format(Date,"%Y"),
         month = format(Date, "%m"),
         day = format(Date, "%d"),
         time = format(Date, "%H")
  )

Comment: That still leaves lots to improve. You do not need `mutate()`.  You do not need to to reformat, and you probably do not want the components as character output.  `POSIXct` converts into `POSIXlt` from which you can access the components.

Comment: (Also with respect to your attempted edit: *Please* do not change code without re-running the output. You were about to break the internal consistency of my answer.)